# Trying to get the result of javascript function using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple program that takes in an input and then should show that input multiplied up to 100.  I am new to this, but have tried to get it to work before posting here.  I have the link to the program that I am referring to.

I want the result to be shown, but I cannot figure out why it is not showing.

You can see what I have below.  I think I do not have the html and javascript hooked up properly.

Here is my html:

```
<body>
  <input type="number" id="NumToBMultiplied" class="value" placeholder="Enter an integer" />
  <input type='submit' id='RunProg' class='button' />
  <p> id='result'</p>
</body>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
h = document.getElementByID('NumToBMultiplied');
var result = document.getElementbyID('RunProg').addEventListener('click', function () {
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        return i * h;
    }
});
document.getElementByID('result').innerHTML = result;
```

http://jsbin.com/wayejequxu/1/edit?html,js,output

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You should add the code to the question instead of just a link.

Comment: `getElementByID` is incorrect, use: `getElementById` lower case `d` instead

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm a bit confused with your question, what's the desired output ? do you really want to multiply `h` x `i`  100 times ?

Comment: Well, the number (100) is arbitrary.  I am working through a few code challenges trying to learn Javascript.  I just picked 100, but I realize 5 would work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From how I understand your code, you are wanting to multiply the input 100 times, then output that into a HTML tag. The result in your example is not being added to the `result` paragraph as it isn't in the loop.

### HTML

This is changed only slightly. Notice the `onClick="solve()"` to the button instead of adding an event listener.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="number" id="NumToBMultiplied" class="value" placeholder="Enter an integer"/>
    <input type="submit" id="RunProg" onClick="solve()" class="button"/>
    <p id="result">&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

### Javascript

I've added a line break after each result of the `for` loop so the result is easier to read. And the output is cleared before a new `solve()` is run.

```
var output = document.getElementById("result");

function solve() {

  var input = document.getElementById("NumToBMultiplied").value;

  output.innerHTML = "";

  for(i=0; i < 100; i++) {

    output.innerHTML += i * input + "<br/>";

  }

}
```

Result here: http://jsbin.com/foduyofewi/1/

Comment: Yes!  This is what I was trying to do.  Now that I see a working solution maybe I can get one to work with an event listener.  Thanks, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to store your result in variable inside a callback and set innerHTML also in callback:

```
document.getElementById('RunProg').addEventListener("click", function() {
    var result = 1;
    var input = +h.value;
    for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        result *= i * input;
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/minehurile/2/edit)

Comment: I cannot run your code successfully, I get:  `ReferenceError: h is not defined`, you may have to initialize `var h`

Comment: When I run your solution it gives one answer.  I was wanting it to show a list.  For example if you put 1 in, then you would get 1x1, 1x2, etc.  To me it seems like a for loop should do that.  Am I missing something? I think a while loop would work, but should it also work with a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Pure Javascript version:

```js
function multiply(x) {
 var result = document.getElementById('result');
    result.innerHTML = x.value * 100;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="NumToBMultiplied" class="value" onchange="multiply(this)" placeholder="Enter an integer"/>
<p id="result"></p>
```

This is the jQuery version:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#NumToBMultiplied').on('change',function(){
      $('#result').text($(this).val()*100);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="NumToBMultiplied" class="value" placeholder="Enter an integer"/>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Is jQuery being used ?

Comment: You may be talking about a different question, not this one.

Comment: Callie asked this: `I have a simple program that takes in an input and then should show that input multiplied up to 100`. I gave him/her a proper solution.

Comment: I am actually trying to avoid jQuery.  I am trying to really learn Javascript so I wanted to try and use something without jQuery.

Comment: Coming in a moment :)

Comment: There, I have reviewed my answer so you have both versions.

Answer (score 0):

Just some modification to your code to remove some of the typos and errors. I'm not sure you can return the result like how you have done it, a more traditional approach is shown below.

Full code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="number" id="NumToBMultiplied" class="value" placeholder="Enter an integer" />
  <input type='submit' id='RunProg' class='button' />
  <p id='result'> </p>
</body>

<script>
h = document.getElementById('NumToBMultiplied').value;
document.getElementById('RunProg').addEventListener('click', function () {
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        var  result = h*i;
        }
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
});


</script>

</html>
```